# Intellij IDEA is disabling imports while developing scala Slick Application with postgres

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, slick

I am doing a program using IntelliJ IDEA 13 . Application uses Scala slick with Postgres 9.3.

My program is below

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._

object GeoLocations extends RichTable[GeoLocation]("geo_location") {
 def latitude = column[Double]("latitude")
 def longitude = column[Double]("longitude")
 def altitude = column[Double]("altitude")

 def * = id.? ~ latitude.? ~ longitude ~ altitude <> (GeoLocation, GeoLocation.unapply _)
 def forInsert = latitude.? ~ longitude ~ altitude <> ({ (lat, long, alt) => GeoLocation(None, lat, long, alt) },
{ g: GeoLocation => Some((g.latitude, g.longitude, g.altitude)) })

}
```

In my program, the below import stament gets disabled automatically and it is causing lots of unwanted errors.

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
```

Comment: What do you mean by "disabled"? An import is just part of the source code, if it isn't commented, the compiler will take it into account.